# spring kafka thorws InstanceAlreadyExistsException exception after setting concurrency > 1

Tags: java, apache-kafka, stomp, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka, everything is working if I don't set the concurrency of ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory, when I set it to a number greater than 1, I get an exception:

> javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException:
>   kafka.consumer:type=app-info,id=client-3

My config:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> 
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new 
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();

    factory.setConcurrency(kafkaConfig.getConcurrency());

    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}
```

properties:

```
kafka.enable-auto-commit=false

kafka.client-id=client-1

kafka.concurrency=2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have opened an [issue for this on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/295). Setting a different `client.id` for each thread is not currently supported.

As a work-around, you could launch a separate `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` for each (which is what the `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` does internally).

**EDIT**

Although not ideal, you can omit the `client.id` and the kafka client will generate one for each (`consumer-1`, `consumer-2` etc)

Comment: I reproduced it; BTW, omitting the `client.id` works, if that's an option for you.

Comment: The client.id is now unique for each consumer in the container by appending `-<n>` (since 1.0.6).